# How can I tell Symfony where to search for a template php file for a view?

Tags: symfony, model-view-controller, mautic

I am coding a simple Plugin for [Mautic](https://www.mautic.org/)
Mautic uses Symfony and hence my plugin has the directory structure (slightly different than standard symfony), which is here described [Mautic Dev Docu](https://developer.mautic.org/#plugin-directory-structure)

In my Controller I return *delegateView* [Further Description](https://developer.mautic.org/#mvc).
For this the `'contentTemplate' => 'MyPluginBundle:details.html.php',` is necessary.
For testing, I upload this raw plugin to the Mautic Plugin folder, and actually everythin seems to work. Firsty, some buttons are added to the dashboard.

Unfortunately, if I call the Controller the logs tell me that he is
`"Unable to find template "MyPlugin:details.html.php" (looked into: .../vendor/knplabs/knp-menu/src/Knp/Menu/Resources/views, [some more paths follow]`
I have placed my details.html.php in nearly all folders of my plugin, just be sure, he can find it. But as I get the message right, he is just looking for the file in a completly wrong directory.
Therefore, my question is, how can I tell him to look in the correct folder for this file?

Thank you in advance

I have compared my code to other Mautic Controller code
[Form Mautic Core Bundle](https://github.com/mautic/mautic/blob/fe4e4547de7ca99259057a7422ab878a50975f6d/app/bundles/LeadBundle/Controller/LeadController.php)

[From Some Plugin](https://github.com/acquia/mc-cs-plugin-custom-objects/blob/staging/Controller/CustomObject/ViewController.php)

I changed `MyPlugin:details.html.php` to `@MyPlugin:details.html.php` to `MauticPlugin/MyPlugin:details.html.php` and even to the entire path, but all without success